# session.setAttribute not working inside strut tag?

Tags: jsp, struts2, httpsession

I am trying to set HttpSession attribute inside strut logic tag. But it doesn't seem to be working. I have asked this my colleagues and searched on google but no one seems to have idea about this.

```
<logic:greaterThan name = "PAYMENT_ATTEMPTS" value ="1" >
     <%session.setAttribute("captchaPresent","true");%> 
     //some extra code
  </logic:greaterThan>
```

the condition for the tag is satisfied because the extra code is running but I am not sure why session is not setting the attribute.

This java code is checking whether the attribute is present in the session and it's returning false always -:

```
 public boolean checkIfCaptchaPosted(HttpServletRequest request){
         HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(session.getAttribute("captchaPresent"));
       }
```

Comment: Mish-moshing tags and scriptlets isn't a good idea anyway. Why not use a tag to set the session value as well? What evidence is there that it isn't working?

Comment: "Why not use a tag to set the session value as well? " - I could do that. But I want to know what can be the reason behind this.